# Como passar props pelo Navigate do react-router?

Tags: react, react-router

Estou tentando passar props pelo **Navigate** do react-router 6 desta forma e não está dando certo.

```
<Navigate to='/editar' state={{from: 10}} />
```

Comment: Já tentou usando um useNavigate desse modo navigate('/editar', { from: 10 }); ?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode sim passar as props dessa maneira. Utilize o useLocation hook para recupera-las na página de destino:

```
<Navigate to='/editar' state={{from: 10}} />

const {state:{from}} = useLocation();
```

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation